# Implement Interfaces or Base class methods for strict overriding?

Tags: react-native, interface, abstract-class

I am working on a react native application, where I need to define some base class with methods to be overridden by subclasses and that should be strictly followed.

Does React Native support concept like interfaces or abstract classes or how we can declare the methods in the base class so that they are required to be implemented by child classes?

Please guide me if there is something to meet the requirement.

Approach:

Base class:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'

export default class AppModule extends Component  {

    static getSearchResult(text) {
        return ['']
    }
}
```

Child Class:

```
import {AppModule} from '../../base/AppModule';

class RoomFinder extends AppModule {

    static getSearchResult(text) {
       return ['x', 'y', 'z'];
    }
    .....
}
```